# Gradual Time Sync for Windows with Powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, time, synchronization

One of my VM servers is 6 hours ahead of the time on our DC server. Unfortunately, we can't just sync the time just like that, as in all 6 hours in one go will impact the historical data collected within the same server. So we need to time-sync against the server by 2 seconds every 1 minute. (I know it will take a lot longer but this way it will not impact the historical data collected).

I am wondering if there is a PowerShell script to achieve this, perhaps scheduled via a batch file.

Any help will be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.

I tried a PowerShell script, but it just syncs the time.

`TimeSync.bat` contains:

```bash
@ECHO OFF
SET ThisScriptsDirectory=%~dp0
SET PowerShellScriptPath=%ThisScriptsDirectory%TimeSync.ps1
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%PowerShellScriptPath%""' -Verb RunAs}";
```

`TimeSync.ps1` contains:

```
Set-Date -Adjust (New-TimeSpan -Seconds -5)
EXIT
```

Comment: Why don't you just sync all machine to one time server.  A time server can be any machine on the network.  A time server is a protocol that periodically sends the DataTime over the network.

Comment: jdweng - the time difference is over 6 hours so we don't want to sync in one go all 6 hours. We want to sync it gradually like 2 seconds every 1 minute. Does this make sense?

Comment: You can schedule a task to execute every minute with the command line version: `schtasks /create /?` - you'll need the `/SC minute /MO 1` switches.

Comment: Thank you Stephan, appreciate it.

Comment: @Stephan, I implemented what you said, but it only works twice and then it stops, even though it is set to run every minute.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a batch script and have it all the PowerShell script; you can just use a PowerShell script by itself.

Here is a PowerShell script that you can just run once, and it will continue to run until the local machine time has caught up with the time pulled from Google.com, and then the script will exit.

```
do
{
    $webResponse = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://www.google.com'
    $dateString = $webResponse.Headers['Date']
    $internetDate = [DateTime]::Parse($dateString)
    $machineDate = Get-Date

    if ($machineDate -lt $internetDate)
    {
        Write-Output "Machine date '$machineDate' is behind internet date '$internetDate', so adjusting machine date by 2 seconds."
        Set-Date -Adjust (New-TimeSpan -Seconds 2)

        Write-Output "Waiting one minute before checking again..."
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Output "Machine date matches internet date"
    }
} while ($machineDate -lt $internetDate)

Write-Output "Machine date is now '$machineDate' and matches the internet date."
```

If needed, you could also add some error handling around the web request to Google and the parsing of the Date header, otherwise the script may terminate early if it is unable to reach Google.

Whichever user you use to run the script will likely need to stay logged in until the script completes, as logging out may terminate the user's PowerShell process. You can perhaps run it as a system account if needed.

I hope this helps.

### Getting time from another server

If you do not want to get the DateTime from Google and instead want to retrieve it from another server on your network, you could use something like:

```
$otherServerDate = Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'YourTimeServer.OnYour.Domain' -ScriptBlock { Get-Date }
```

And use `$otherServerDate` instead of `$internetDate`.

This assumes that the server you are running your script on and the other time server are on the same network with the necessary ports open, and the account the script is running as has permissions to connect to the other time server. You can use the `-Credentials` parameter to provide a different account that does have access if needed.

Comment: This is great Dan and really appreciated this.  I am going to try it now but if I want to use a system account to avoid the user log-off situation, how can I build that system account and its passwords in this script so that this script will run even the user is logged off?

Comment: There's a few different ways to run it as a system user: https://powershell-guru.com/powershell-tip-53-run-powershell-as-system/ Using a one-time scheduled task that runs as SYSTEM and calls your PowerShell script might be the easiest.